How to replace NaN and/or Inf with NA in a pipe chain in R
I'm wondering how to replace all Inf and NaN elements in numeric columns in my OUTPUT with NA in a pipe chain?
I tried the following without success:
OUTPUT %>% replace(is.infinite(.)|!is.numeric(.), NA)
library(tidyverse)

DATA <- structure(list(InstID = c(2063L, 2063L, 2063L, 2063L, 2113L, 
                                  2113L, 2113L, 2113L, 2440L, 2441L, 2441L, 2441L), 
                       InstNm = c("Adel SD 21", "Adel SD 21", "Adel SD 21", "Adel SD 21", "Adrian SD 61", 
                                  "Adrian SD 61","Adrian SD 61", "Adrian SD 61", "Alabama Department of Education", 
                                  "Alaska Department of Education", "Alaska Department of Education", 
                                  "Alaska Department of Education"),
                       SchlYr = c(2021L, 2122L, 2223L,2324L, 2021L, 2122L, 2223L, 
                                  2324L, 2324L, 2021L, 2122L, 2223L), 
                       Total_Enrollment = c(17L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 262L, 257L, 264L, 
                                          275L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 7L), 
                       Total_EL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 25L, 24L, 25L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                       Total_Arriver = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), 
                  row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")


OUTPUT <- DATA %>% group_by(InstNm) %>%
     mutate(Total_Enroll_change = round(((Total_Enrollment - lag(Total_Enrollment))/ lag(Total_Enrollment))*100, 1),
                       Total_EL_change = round(((Total_EL - lag(Total_EL))/ lag(Total_EL))*100,1),
                       Total_Arriver_change = round(((Total_Arriver - lag(Total_Arriver))/ lag(Total_Arriver))*100, 1)) 


Using dplyr::across and an if_else you could do:
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

DATA |>
  mutate(
    Total_Enroll_change = round(((Total_Enrollment - lag(Total_Enrollment)) / lag(Total_Enrollment)) * 100, 1),
    Total_EL_change = round(((Total_EL - lag(Total_EL)) / lag(Total_EL)) * 100, 1),
    Total_Arriver_change = round(((Total_Arriver - lag(Total_Arriver)) / lag(Total_Arriver)) * 100, 1),
    .by = InstNm
  ) |>
  mutate(
    across(
      ends_with("_change"),
      ~ if_else(is.nan(.x) | is.infinite(.x), NA, .x)
    )
  )
#>    InstID                          InstNm SchlYr Total_Enrollment Total_EL
#> 1    2063                      Adel SD 21   2021               17        0
#> 2    2063                      Adel SD 21   2122               13        0
#> 3    2063                      Adel SD 21   2223               11        0
#> 4    2063                      Adel SD 21   2324               13        0
#> 5    2113                    Adrian SD 61   2021              262       25
#> 6    2113                    Adrian SD 61   2122              257       24
#> 7    2113                    Adrian SD 61   2223              264       25
#> 8    2113                    Adrian SD 61   2324              275       24
#> 9    2440 Alabama Department of Education   2324                1        0
#> 10   2441  Alaska Department of Education   2021                3        0
#> 11   2441  Alaska Department of Education   2122                4        0
#> 12   2441  Alaska Department of Education   2223                7        0
#>    Total_Arriver Total_Enroll_change Total_EL_change Total_Arriver_change
#> 1              0                  NA              NA                   NA
#> 2              0               -23.5              NA                   NA
#> 3              0               -15.4              NA                   NA
#> 4              0                18.2              NA                   NA
#> 5              0                  NA              NA                   NA
#> 6              0                -1.9            -4.0                   NA
#> 7              1                 2.7             4.2                   NA
#> 8              0                 4.2            -4.0                 -100
#> 9              0                  NA              NA                   NA
#> 10             0                  NA              NA                   NA
#> 11             0                33.3              NA                   NA
#> 12             0                75.0              NA                   NA


These NaN and Infare appearing because there are divisions by zero in your formulas. Instead of dealing with the effect, it might be better to fix the cause.
# Pkgs --------------------------------------------------------------------
library(dplyr) # And `tibble` 

# Toy data ----------------------------------------------------------------
DATA <- tibble::tribble(
  ~InstID,                           ~InstNm, ~SchlYr, ~Total_Enrollment, ~Total_EL, ~Total_Arriver,
    2063L,                      "Adel SD 21",   2021L,               17L,        0L,             0L,
    2063L,                      "Adel SD 21",   2122L,               13L,        0L,             0L,
    2063L,                      "Adel SD 21",   2223L,               11L,        0L,             0L,
    2063L,                      "Adel SD 21",   2324L,               13L,        0L,             0L,
    2113L,                    "Adrian SD 61",   2021L,              262L,       25L,             0L,
    2113L,                    "Adrian SD 61",   2122L,              257L,       24L,             0L,
    2113L,                    "Adrian SD 61",   2223L,              264L,       25L,             1L,
    2113L,                    "Adrian SD 61",   2324L,              275L,       24L,             0L,
    2440L, "Alabama Department of Education",   2324L,                1L,        0L,             0L,
    2441L,  "Alaska Department of Education",   2021L,                3L,        0L,             0L,
    2441L,  "Alaska Department of Education",   2122L,                4L,        0L,             0L,
    2441L,  "Alaska Department of Education",   2223L,                7L,        0L,             0L)


# Fixing the cause --------------------------------------------------------
OUTPUT <- mutate(
  DATA, .by = InstNm, 
  
  across(                            # Applies the same formula to all
    .cols = starts_with("Total_"),   # `Total_` columns
    
    .fns = list(
      "change" = \(i) if_else(       # Tests if previous value is `0`
        lag(i, default = 0) == 0,    # If `0` --> `NA_real_` 
        NA_real_, 
        round(100 * ((i - lag(i))/lag(i)), digits = 1))),
    
    .names = "{.col}_{.fn}"))

# Output ------------------------------------------------------------------
OUTPUT[, c(1, 7:9)] # Just for better visualisation
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    InstID Total_Enrollment_change Total_EL_change Total_Arriver_change
#>     <int>                   <dbl>           <dbl>                <dbl>
#>  1   2063                    NA              NA                     NA
#>  2   2063                   -23.5            NA                     NA
#>  3   2063                   -15.4            NA                     NA
#>  4   2063                    18.2            NA                     NA
#>  5   2113                    NA              NA                     NA
#>  6   2113                    -1.9            -4                     NA
#>  7   2113                     2.7             4.2                   NA
#>  8   2113                     4.2            -4                   -100
#>  9   2440                    NA              NA                     NA
#> 10   2441                    NA              NA                     NA
#> 11   2441                    33.3            NA                     NA
#> 12   2441                    75              NA                     NA

Created on 2024-09-19 with reprex v2.1.0
